# How to connect new user to hotspot while vpn running?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, wifi-hotspot, openvpn

I'm running marshmallow  (6.0.1) rooted. I run the following commands

```
iptables -F

iptables -t filter -F FORWARD

iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING

iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

ip rule add from 192.168.43.0/24 lookup 61

ip route add default dev tun0 scope link table 61

ip route add 192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link table 61

ip route add broadcast 255.255.255.255 dev wlan0 scope link table 61
```

So I can tether the vpn connection. My problem is once tethered no new client can connect it stays at obtaining iptables address. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you mean "stuck at  obtaining **IP address** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Normally in plain hotspot mode (without VPN setup), clients will get
>   an IP address from the **phone's DHCP server**.
>
> However, when the OpenVPN client is running, by default it is
>   redirecting all traffic to the OpenVPN server, meaning any client
>   traffic is also being redirected. Hence, the clients aren't talking to
>   the phone's DHCP server any more - they are talking to the OpenVPN
>   server, and if that doesn't provide an IP address via DCHP then the
>   clients connection attempts will "hang".

There are possible workaround to keep tethering functionality on other connecting clients:

1. **Using postrouting and forwarding rules**

You can just add just  post-routing  and forwarding rules i.e

```
iptables -t filter -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

(this is the solution I'm using currently),

---

2. **Setup IP addresses manually**

   - You may need to assign other clients IP manually (static IP
     address) to bypass DCHP server.

---

3. **Exclude hotspot subnet from tunnel**

> - The fix is to identify the subnet used by the hotspot service and
>     manually add it to Excluded Networks for the connection. i.e
>     `192.168.43.0/24`.
> - Now when the tunnel is initiated the hotspot subnet is always excluded from routing through the tunnel regardless of startup
>     sequence and tethering always works.

or simply excluding `192.168.43.0/24` (and including  `0.0.0.0/0`) rules from iptables.

Acknowledgements

- [Wi-Fi hotspot enabled on host device with OpenVPN connected... connected client devices have no internet](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/issues/34)